# SQL connection leak, can I see which query is not closing its connection?

Tags: sql-server

It seems one of my queries is not closing its connection.

This is the query I use to get the count:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sys.dm_exec_connections where client_net_address = '192.168.0.82'
```

When I step through with the debugger, there is no exception thrown, Visual Studio just acts the same way as if the page request was finished, the call stack empties, the web page never finishes it's load cycle, and hangs. An `iisreset` is required to drop the connections in use.

This page request does a lot of queries. Finding the culprit is possible but is there a more time efficient way find which query?

Is there a query, similar to the one I posted above, that I can run on SQL Server to see what query has request the open connection without closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your query is still executing?

Use SQL Server Management Studio's Activity Monitor to find the SQL Server's activity. Right click your server, select 'Activity Monitor'.

Open the 'Processes' area, and you'll see the activity that you're looking for. You can right-click each entry to find the statement that was being executed.

Answer (score 1):

The connection isn't going to be kept open by a single query.  The connection is kept open by not properly disposing of `SqlConnection` objects.  Check your code and verify that you are using the `using` statement when dealing with SqlConnection, as per this example: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/01/13/773.aspx